# Out of time exception when calling next on ResultSet in Java

Tags: java, database, resultset

I'm working with database, and I'm selecting from it some stuff, like I did thousand times. But this time, the program just freezes when calling `resultSet.next()`, and after a while throws out of time exception. Any ideas, where could I have mistake? Here's my code:

```
 try {
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        query = connection.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT * FROM INGREDIENTS WHERE RECIPEID = ?");

        query.setLong(1, recipe.getId());

        ResultSet resultsDB = query.executeQuery();

        SortedSet<Ingredient> result = new TreeSet<Ingredient>();
        while (resultsDB.next()) {
            Ingredient output = rowToIngredient(resultsDB);
            validate(output);

            result.add(output);
        }
        connection.commit();
        return result;
     }
```

The Program freezes exactly at `resultsDB.next()` when it is called as condition in while cycle. When this part of code is executed 1st time, it works, when the program reaches there second time with another data, `.next()` method freezes  the program. The program never gets into the cycle, I used breakpoints and it fails on the line where the condition is evalueated. Thanks for advices

This whole code is in for cycle, is it OK? As far as I am using data source, it should be

Error:

```
java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.closeOnTransactionError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.movePosition(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:207)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:207)
    at fi.muni.pv168.RecipebookImpl.getIngredientsOfRecipe(RecipebookImpl.java:53)
    at fi.muni.pv168.RecipebookImpl.isIngredientInRecipe(RecipebookImpl.java:324)
    at fi.muni.pv168.RecipebookImpl.addIngredientsToRecipe(RecipebookImpl.java:92)
    at fi.muni.pv168.RecipebookImplTest.testFindRecipesByIngredients(RecipebookImplTest.java:390)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 46 more
```

and there are few more

Comment: no, I tried breakpoints, the program never gets into the cycle, it fails on the line, where the condition is evaluated

Comment: @orid Where do you find a `hasNext` method? [I don't see one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

Comment: its only next(), not hasNext()

Comment: It hangs on the query.executeQuery() statement?  Did you try running the select statement through some other sql front-end to see if it works?

Comment: @MilošLukačka you are right of course. My comment is misleading.

Comment: @OldProgrammer yes, when this method is called 1st time in program runtime, it works, it only crashs on 2nd calling

Comment: @bizmark I cant past the last row, the resultset is created 2 lines before calling.next, and the method .next is boolean so it should return false if there is no other row

Comment: yes, I didn't read doc properly, so retracting comment. My bad.

Comment: Crashes on 2nd call? Try `resultsDB.close()` at the end. Also, I could be wrong, but I suspect the `commit` is not required (I think that's more for `INSERT` / `UPDATE`).

Comment: what are you expecting the in 2nd iteration? Is the data integrity of the resultset ok?

Comment: @Dukeling the commit is required because the autoCommit is set to false. resultsDB.close() does not help.

Comment: @bizmark how can I check data integrity of resultSet?

Comment: is OK that this whole code is in FOR cycle?

Comment: I mean are there any null values or something unexpected in the fields of the ResultSet? what happens if you run an SQL query against your database using mySQL workbench or Oracle or whatever DB you are using?

Comment: I'm using derby, there are no null values or anything unexpected, its just regular DB

Comment: Please show us the full stacktrace. I'm unaware of a "out of time" exception in Java. You should also state which DBMS you are using (Postgres? Oracle?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have another concurrent non-committed transaction which is updating a row that you're trying to read. This causes the row to be locked, and your transaction to wait until this lock is released.

If you're using a tool to execute requests on the database, make sure to commit or rollback the current transaction in this tool. If you have another application, or another thread in the same application using the same database, check if it doesn't have long-running transactions.

Comment: I went through program step by step to this issue, and I haven't figured out anything. Is there some other way how to check what is using DB? P.S. I have only 1 thread

Comment: I don't know what was wrong, but I reorganized my code a little bit and it works now. Thanks